Proof that the closed convex hull of a weakly convergent sequence has empty interior using properties of $c_0$?
Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space, and $x_n\to 0$ weakly in $X.$ Let $K$ be the closed convex hull of $\{x_n\}.$
I remember a proof that $K$ has empty interior as follows: define a map $T: X^\ast \to c_0$ by $Tf = (f(x_n))_{n\in \mathbb N}.$ If $K$ has nonempty interior, then $T$ is clearly an injective embedding. Thus, we have a closed subspace $E$ of $c_0$ isomorphic to $X^\ast.$
Further, we use the fact that every closed subspace $E$ of $c_0$ has a closed subspace isomorphic to $c_0.$ So we have the embedding $c_0 \to X^\ast \to c_0.$
This is where I get stuck - I do not know why this leads to a contradiction, and I struggle to find the reference for this proof. Does anyone have a clue?  ${{}}$

If $K$ has interior points then so does the closed absolutely convex hull $M$ of the weak null sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which is thus the unit ball of an equivalent norm on $X$.
Moreover, $M$ is weakly compact because it is the image $S(B_{\ell^1})$ of the linear map $S:\ell^1\to X$, $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_nx_n$ (the series converges since $x_n$ is bounded in the Banach space), $S$ is $\sigma(\ell^1,c_0)-\sigma(X,X^*)$ continuous (since $x_n\to 0$ weakly), and $B_{\ell^1}$ is $\sigma(\ell^1,c_0)$-compact.
Therefore, $X$ and hence $X^*$ are reflexive and cannot contain a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$.

Thank you. That's exactly what it is.

Note that
If a dual space $X^*$ contains a copy of $c_0$ then it contains a copy of $\ell_\infty$. See Theorem V.10 in J. Diestel, Sequences and series in Banach spaces. Springer 1984,
Since $\ell_\infty$ is non-separable, there is no isomorphic embedding $T:X^*\to c_0$.
